# in Rails, how to I access the other side of a rich join?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, relationship

when I type "Student.find(1).togethers" in the rails console, I get this array:

```
=> [#<Together id: 1, student_id: 1, teacher_id: 1, summary: "good", created_at: "2012-12-12 01:56:05", updated_at: "2012-12-12 01:56:05">]
```

now how do I access the teacher with **"teacher_id: 1"** ????

I would like to do something like:

```
Student.find(1).teacher
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Student.find(1).togethers.each{|t| t.teacher}
```

This should work fine if you have `belonge_to :teachers` in you Together model,

Ideally to use `Student.find(1).teacher` 
you should define 'student has many teachers `through` together`